# Samsung s3 is not returning image data into URI after capturing image whereas on all other devices, it is working fine

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I have been testing my Android application that uses device camera to capture photo. This application is working fine in all the devices except Samsung Galaxy s3.

The problem is that I am not getting any image after capturing using default camera.

Could anyone help me if one had same issue and resolved it?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
Strange I download PhotoIntentActivity code and it is also not working. It is working for small photo, but when pass URI the same issue.

Comment: any error warning in logcat if so paste it also here

Comment: No error. It is not returning any error. However If I am not setting Extra_output for file, it is working fine.

Comment: Please add your code maybe there is a small error.

Comment: Thanks rekire for response. But I download PhotoIntentActivity code and it is also not working. It is working for small photo, but when pass URI the same issue.

Comment: What are operating system versions of devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks all for your response. However I found the solution. I changed my photo capture activity config from manifest file to

```
    <activity android:name="YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

I will go through the document once again for complete understanding, however right now it is working fine.

Comment: thanks a lot! been trying to find out the solution for s3 problem. this works for me. :)

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning behind this fix?

Comment: hey can you please me with the same problem. The difference is just that i am dealing with multiple images